# Adding javascript to drupal 7 is giving error

Tags: 7

i am trying to add code using drupal_add_js and separate .js file. Its giving the Jquery is not found error.

```
(function ($) {
 function mobilizeCustomInit() {

                 // Add new Javascript and CSS files to mobile
                 // file loading list

                 // Note: Slashdot at the beginning of the filename
                 // indicates that the file path is relative to the HTML file location.
                 // This is an internal trick of mobilize.js.

               //  mobilize.cdnOptions.javascriptBundles.push("drupal/sites/all/themes/kanji/mobilize.yoursite.js");
               /**
 * This file is executed when the site is loaded in mobile mode.
 */

/**
 * This file is executed when the site is loaded in mobile mode.
 */

mobilize.extend(mobilize, {

    constructBody : function() {
        // Map different elements to jQuery Mobile theme 
        this.constructHeader();

        this.constructContent();
        this.constructNavigation();

        this.constructFooter();
    },

    /**
     * Create mobile site header name and buttons 
     */
    constructHeader : function() {
        // Map title and header buttons jQuery Mobile 

        // This is the mobile target element 
        // which will contain the title.
        $('.mobile-header').css('display','TRUE');
        var mobileHeader = $("#mobile-body div[data-role=header]");

        // Pick the current page title from <header> section
        var title = $("header h1").text();

        // Set mobile header title to the same text
        var h1 = $("h1").text(title);
        mobileHeader.append(h1);        

    },

    /**
     * Move content area from web site to mobile site
     */
    constructContent : function() {
        var content = $("#content");

        // Place content HTML to mobile content area container
        var mobileContent = $("#mobile-body div[data-role=content]");
        mobileContent.append(content);
    },

    /**
     * Create mobile footer
     */
    constructFooter : function() {
        var footer = $("footer").children();

        // Place content HTML to mobile content area container
        var mobileFooter = $("#mobile-body div[data-role=footer]");
        mobileFooter.append(footer);

    },


    /**
     * Use jQuery Mobile nested list to create a navigation.
     * 
     */
    constructNavigation : function() {

        // Get list of items which contain links for the navigation building
        var items = $("#navss li");

        // Create navigation list
        var list = $("<ul class='page-list' data-role='listview' data-inset=true>");

        // Add list header
        list.prepend("<li data-role='list-divider'>Pages</li>"); 

        // Add list items
        items.each(function () {
            var output = $("<li role='option'>");
            output.append($(this).find("a"));
            output.appendTo(list);
        });


        // Put list below content
        var mobileContent = $("#mobile-body div[data-role=content]");
        mobileContent.append(list);        

    }


});
                 mobilize.cdnOptions.cssBundles.push("./mobile-style.css");                 
            }           
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Can you post your `drupal_add_js` code? Also where are you calling it from (template.php/template file/module/etc.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to pass the $ alias to your mobilizeCustomInit() function.

Either way, the easiest way to solve your problem would be to just use "jQuery" directly in your code instead of the $ alias if its still giving you problems!

Comment: The `mobilizeCustomInit()` function is already contained in a closure which is being passed the `$` alias so there's no reason to pass it through again. Also the `jQuery undefined` message will be referring to the `(jQuery)` reference at the end of the closure. If `jQuery` isn't defined at that point it can't possibly work when used directly inside the closure itself...the `jQuery` variable is `undefined` in the global scope.